# Unity3d. RenderTexture with Video Player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, video, render, texture2d

When creating (instance) an object on the scene, in a custom script (MonoBehaviour) script, a RendereTexture object is created and after the destruction of this object, is the memory for RendererTexture also freed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could open the Profiler and simply test this yourself.

**Spoiler: I think not.**

Afaik any `Texture` is not automatically GC collected but needs to be explicitly destroyed

If you want to be sure you could simply do e.g.

```
private void OnDestroy()
{ 
    if(renderTextureReference) Destroy(renderTextureReference); 
}
```

in your component.

Also have a look at [`RenderTexture.Release`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderTexture.Release.html)

> This function releases the hardware resources used by the render texture. The texture itself is not destroyed, and will be automatically created again when being used.
>
> As with other "native engine object" types, it is important to pay attention to the lifetime of any render textures and release them when you are finished using them, **as they will not be garbage collected like normal managed types**.